# Book about man hired to paint green square

Tags: identification-request

I'm trying to find the title of a novel I read back in the 1990s. The only thing I recall about it is the somewhat absurdist premise of a man being hired to paint a green square on a patch of ground. Thanks in advance for your help!

As I recall, it was a hardcover edition, and was likely published between the 1960s-1990s. It took place during a contemporary time period. Written in English.

Comment: Welcome to Literature SE! Can you remember any more details about this novel - e.g. was it hardback or paperback? thick novel or thin? any details about the cover? historical, modern, or futuristic? set in the real world or a fantasy one? what country/language was it written in? published in the 1990s, or much older? *Anything* else you can remember might help to narrow the search, and I'm sure you can jog more from your memory if you ask the right questions :-)

Comment: Hi Rand, thanks for the comment. As I recall, it was a hardcover edition, and was likely published between the 1960s-1990s. It took place during a contemporary time period. Written in English. Thanks again for your note!